# NotFittedError make_pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have following pipeline

```
num_pipe = make_pipeline(
    StandardScaler()
)
cat_pipe = make_pipeline(
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"),
)
preprocessor_tree = make_column_transformer(
    (num_pipe, selector(dtype_include="number")),
    (cat_pipe, selector(dtype_include="category")),
    n_jobs=2,
)
bag_clf = make_pipeline(
    preprocessor_tree,
    BalancedBaggingClassifier(
        base_estimator=HistGradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=42),
        n_estimators=10,
        random_state=42,
        n_jobs=2,
    ),
)
cv_result = cross_validate(bag_clf, X_train, y_train, scoring=scoring)
```

after cross validation i try

```
y_pred = bag_clf.predict(X_test)
```

and got  `This ColumnTransformer instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.`
How evaluate classifiers on unseen data ?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to `.fit` your pipeline after cross validation, as the error is indicating.